# Exact Equation Solution | Position of the arbitrary constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solving an ordinary differential equation using exact equation method will lead to an equation with an arbitrary constant. I always isolate the arbitrary constant, c, on the other side, while the expression of the variables on the opposite side However, I saw examples where the arbitrary constant and the expression are not isolated from each other. For example;

The arbitrary constant is isolated on the other side:
$x^2 + 2xy - y^2 = c$

The arbitrary constant is not isolated on the other side:
$y^3 + 2y^2 = 4xy + c$

Is the position of the arbitrary constant significant? Or not?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: A constant is a constant on the left side or the right side. I prefer for aesthetic reasons to isolate it in the final answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter, although it will of course change what the actual number $c$ corresponding to a given solution is.

Comment: I see. However, I just curious why other examples isolate the arbitrary constant, while other don't.

Comment: @HYDR0GEN There's no particular reason for either way of writing it.